# Linux kernel : Setting the permissions for a /dev file that was created via create_device()

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-kernel, chardev

I am making a small linux module that is a driver to a char device.
In my code i create the device class, than the device it self and thus a /dev file is
created in my system. the problem is that the /dev file has only root permissions and the user
has neither read nor write nor execute permissions on that file, i would like to change the
/dev file permissions.

I have searched the web for answers and what i found was to change the udev file, but this
solution will not work in my case because i need the permissions to change dynamicly when the module is loaded into the kernel. The module i am writing will not always run on my machine, thus i need it to change the permissions "on the fly".

```
major_number_firewall = register_chrdev(0, device_name_firewall, &my_file_implementation_firewall);

device_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, class_name_firewall);

log_file_device = device_create(device_class, NULL, MKDEV(major_number_firewall, MINOR_LOG), NULL, device_name_log_file);
```

Is there a function for changing the permissions?

Answer (score 5):

1. You can write a small [udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) for achieving this.
2. If you are implementing a char device driver, then consider using `misc_register()` and `misc_unregister()` which is wrapper over the above calls (`device_create()`...). Refer to [struct miscdevice](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.3/include/linux/miscdevice.h#L50)

   ```
   struct miscdevice  {
       int minor;
       const char *name;
       const struct file_operations *fops;
       struct list_head list;
       struct device *parent;
       struct device *this_device;
       const char *nodename;
       umode_t mode;
   };
   ```

You can use the member `(struct miscdevice *)->mode` to set the appropriate permissions (S_IRUGO | S_IRWXUGO | S_IALLUGO | etc ...)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Rocoder meant was to first change the permissions of your device file using

> int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode); OR int fchmod(int fd, mode_t mode);

in your user space application. Then open the device file using open() and do whatever.

also note: we cannot have a program chmod itself to super user mode within itself. This is to ensure no illegal program takes hold of the system.

Answer (score 1):

To set the permission for your misc device you can use the mode field as follows.

```
static struct miscdevice somedevice = {
    .minor  = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    .name   = DEVICE_NAME,
    .fops   = &some_fops,
    .mode   = 0666,
};
```

This will set read/write access to all.
To perform read/write operation you do not need to be root.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

`#include <sys/stat.h>`

`int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);`
OR
`int fchmod(int fd, mode_t mode);`

or inside `/etc/udev/udev.conf,`

you can modify the `default_mode = "0660"`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but it is impossible to inclue the <sys/stat.h> file inside a kernel module. and as i mentioned changing the udev file is not an option.